# Is there any workaround for not having XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook support in Excel 2003?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2003

I keep getting `Error 24:'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat' does not contain a definition for 'xlOpenXMLWorkbook'` in a data export procedure to Excel. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
string path = Path.GetTempFileName();

if (File.Exists(path))
    File.Delete(path);

workbook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false,
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, true,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
workbook.Close();
```

My guess is because I'm using `Excel 2003`, which does not support  `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, so I'm just wondering if there is any workaround about this error? Or is updating Excel really mandatory?

Comment: There are third party options available to work with Excel that do not require having a specific version of Excel installed to use. The one I've found that works the best is EPPlus. Rewriting your code would be a hassle, but the library is easy to use, and you won't have to worry about not having to upgrade to a newer version of Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat(v=office.11).aspx) and [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279(v=office.12).aspx) in the MSDN database, it's safe to assume that this is not supported by Excel 2003, which means you have to update to at least Excel 2007.

In any case, `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` is equivalent to `.xlsx`. There are times when `.xls` should be enough, which in this case is accessed by using `xlWorkbookNormal` instead. This is supported in Excel 2003.